# on scroll div gradually fadein fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to creating fadein fadeout effect with scrolling but not figure out how . it is like `http://www.popsci.com/` . There If scroll then background image (div id fixed-image ) get fading. Them code something like. But I cannot figure out yet how to easily apply in my code. Would guys please check it my code .

```
var opacity = 1;
      var img = element.find('img');
      // Look for featured stories.
      if (element.length > 0) {
        // Attach background image element.
        $('#page-wrapper').prepend('<div id="fixed-image" style="background-image: url(\'' + img.attr('data-lgsrc') + '\');"></div>');
        img.addClass('hidden');
        var scrollPercent;
        $(window).scroll(function() {
          // When User scrolls down, determine percentage from top to bottom of window.
          scrollPercent = (($(window).scrollTop() / $(window).height() * 1.9) - 0.9);
          if (scrollPercent < 0) {
            $('#fixed-image').css({
              '-webkit-filter'  : 'blur(0px)',
              '-moz-filter'     : 'blur(0px)',
              '-o-filter'       : 'blur(0px)',
              '-ms-filter'      : 'blur(0px)',
              'filter'          : 'blur(0px)'
            });
          }
          var opacityCount = 1.5 - Math.min(1.5, (scrollPercent + 1));
          $('#fixed-image').css('opacity', opacityCount);
          if (scrollPercent <= 1) {
            $('#fixed-image').css('opacity', opacityCount);
            $('#fixed-image').css({
              '-webkit-filter'  : 'blur(' + scrollPercent * 10 + 'px)',
              '-moz-filter'     : 'blur(' + scrollPercent * 10 + 'px)',
              '-o-filter'       : 'blur(' + scrollPercent * 10 + 'px)',
              '-ms-filter'      : 'blur(' + scrollPercent * 10 + 'px)',
              'filter'          : 'blur(' + scrollPercent * 10 + 'px)'
            });
          }
          else {
            $('.content-wrapper-outer').css('background-color', 'rgba(255,255,255,' + opacity + ')');
```

my demo is here **https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/6e6dbr6j/1/**

i want **slider** class will be fadeIn and fadeout gradually base on scrolling

**UPDATE**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    $(".slider").css("opacity", 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250);
  });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cyber007/6e6dbr6j/2/ this one work fine. jus one minor think in console i saw that opacity value keep running after **0** even going **-** value. i don't think after value **0** no need down value more

Comment: What are you trying to fadeout? whatever image showing in the slider? What is "element" in your JS code?

Comment: i just update my question. i want slider div will fadein fade out like reference site. in slider div. no matter what is content. current for demo i just put bxslide. thanks for your response

Comment: your new fiddle still does not have your js code, as in your question. Please check it out and add it as it is in your original code.

Comment: i updated more. problem almost 98% solve.

Comment: Just test if it's less than zero, and if true set to zero...

`if (opacity < 0 ) opacity = 0;`

https://jsfiddle.net/6e6dbr6j/3/

Comment: ...Although [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) that "Any value outside the interval [0 to 1], though valid, is clamped to the nearest limit in the range." In that case `if (opacity < 0 ) opacity = 0;` is unnecessary.

Comment: @Rafi . you can make answer this question. then i can mark this question Solve and you can get point :) as your answer as comment i can not make it solve. thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a function to clip opacity at 0, although [according to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/opacity):  "Any value outside the interval [0 to 1], though valid, is clamped to the nearest limit in the range," so it's not strictly necessary.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var opacity = 1 - $(window).scrollTop() / 250;
    if (opacity < 0 ) opacity = 0;
    $(".slider").css("opacity", opacity);
});
```

**UPDATE**

For arbitrary start and end of your transition, use the linear equation [image], like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var start = 200, end = 600;
    var opacity = 1 - ($(window).scrollTop() - start) / (end - start);
    if (opacity > 1 ) opacity = 1;
    if (opacity < 0 ) opacity = 0;
    $(".slider").css("opacity", opacity);
  });
```

[Here's a JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6e6dbr6j/5/)

Comment: thanks for answer.

i am just think how to set scroll starting point. i mean opacity will start when scroll position 200 then end by 600